# Jasper server error when referencing a custom function

Tags: jasper-reports, jasperserver

I am using JasperStudio v6.3.1 and I followed the tutorial on how to create a custom Java function that I can use in my report. Everything works fine in Jasper Studio, but when I publish the report to the Jasper Server, then it fails. The report does exist on the Server, but does not run after publishing the latest changes.

"Errors were encountered when compiling report expressions class file: 1. The method CURRENT_MONTH_BEGINNING() is undefined for the type TotalTaskHrsOnly..."

This error is generated because the custom Java functions that I made in Jasper Studio did not get published to the remote Jasper Server. I need help with getting these files onto the Jasper Server, but I'm not sure how to do that within Jasper Studio, Jasper Server, or if I need to log into the remote server, and drop the java files in there somewhere. Can someone please tell me how I can add the custom functionality onto the Jasper Server?

Comment: I followed the tutorial that was available in the Help menu. Help>Jaspersoft Studio Documentation>Tutorials>Variables and Expressions>Expression Editor: How to extend it and contribute your own functions

Comment: Here is a link that explains what I had to do for my functions to work on the Jasper Server: https://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/1085241/how-publish-custom-functions-jasper-studio-jasper-server#comment-848456

Answer (score 1):

I worked with custom Java functions in Jasperserver reports for quite awhile. Some of the things you will need to ensure:

- You import the java class at the top of the Jasper report .jrxml file
- The Jar is deployed to the server and is labeled as a resource in the repository. It looks like this is the part you're getting stuck on. If you log into Jasperserver and go to the repository, you can open a folder and upload a new file/resource.
- The report references the jar in the repository as a resource

Does this help?

Comment: This does help thank you. One thing I failed to do at first was to include the 2 properties files that are generated when creating a new functions library. This link has a step by step instruction on what I had to do in order make the custom functions work. https://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/1085241/how-publish-custom-functions-jasper-studio-jasper-server#comment-848456